# Android SDK path issue when using calabash-android

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, calabash, calabash-android

I'm getting a **"Could not find an Android SDK please make sure it is installed"** error when trying to run calabash-android commands. I've installed the Android SDK via brew. Here are the contents of my .bash_profile:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.2
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        source ~/.bashrc
fi

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home

export PATH
```

Here's my $PATH:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/mchumak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/mchumak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/mchumak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.2/tools:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.2/platform-tools:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.2/build-tools:/Users/mchumak/.rvm/bin:/Users/mchumak/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/mchumak/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

"which android" produces:

```
/usr/local/bin/android
```

The contents of that particular file are:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOOL="/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.2/tools/android"
exec "$TOOL" "$@"
```

I can run the Android SDK Manager from the command line just fine, and it shows the correct SDK path (/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.2).

I'm stumped. Any ideas why calabash-android can't find the SDK?

Comment: Calabash uses adb.  Does 'adb' work properly?  Also what does 'which adb' return?

Comment: @alannichols I can start a server using adb successfully. `which adb` returns `/usr/local/bin/adb`. The contents of that file are `PLATFORM_TOOL="/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.2/platform-tools/adb"`
`test -x "$PLATFORM_TOOL" && exec "$PLATFORM_TOOL" "$@"`
`echo "It appears you do not have 'Android SDK Platform-tools' installed."`
`echo "Use the 'android' tool to install them: "`
`echo "    android update sdk --no-ui --filter 'platform-tools'"`

Comment: Hmm, my only guess would be that it's something to do with the linking from eg. /usr/local/bin/adb to where it's actually installed, /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.2/platform-tools/adb. Can you try removing the android commands from /usr/local/bin/ and try it again.  My setup doesn't have the commands linked from /usr/local/bin/ but other than that I think it looks fine.  If that doesn't work I'd suggest a manual install.

Comment: @alannichols Unfortunately removing the alias files from /usr/local/bin/ didn't solve it. `which android` returns the correct immediate path (`/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.2/tools/android`), but I'm still getting the same error. I'll try installing the gem manually.

Comment: Still getting the same issue after installing the gem manually.

Comment: Sorry I meant to try installing the sdk manually, i.e. not with brew and to point ANDROID_HOME to there and see how you get on.

Comment: Choose the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fix your issue,

1. `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/Users/#username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/sdk/platform-tools/" >> ~/.bash_profile`
2. install android-platform-tools -> `brew install android-platform-tools`

**- Also ensure yourself have admin rights**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your $PATH output seems like android sdk path isnt loaded into PATH. Add below to your .bash_profile

PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed the .bash_profile to add ANDROID_HOME to the PATH variable and started a new bash instance, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
calabash-android run /Users/marcg/Downloads/app-news.apk
```

I received that following error

> Could not find any platform directory in  '/Users/marcg/Library/Android/sdk/platforms'

I corrected this with the symlink below:

```
/Users/marcg/Library/Android/sdk/platforms
platforms$ ln -s ../platform-tools/ platform
```

I ran again and get an error that the android jar was missing from a standard directory of `/Users/marcg/Library/Android/sdk/platforms`

I then copied that android.jar to this platforms dir

Dir now looks like:

```
/Users/marcg/Library/Android/sdk/platforms
us164912:platforms marcg$ ls -l
total 49640
-rwxr-xr-x   1 marcg Users  25409822 Oct  5 09:26 android.jar
lrwxr-xr-x   1 marcg Users        18 Oct  5 09:14 platform -> ../platform-tools/
```

Still getting

> Did not find 'android.jar' in any standard directory of '/Users/marcg/Library/Android/sdk/platforms'. Calabash will therefore take longer to load

I copied the `android.jar` to the `platform-tools` directory and remaining error went away.

Steps to correct:

1. Make a symlink in platforms that points to platform-tools
   `ln -s ../platform-tools/ platform`
2. Copy the android.jar to the platform-tools dir

Would be better if the framework allowed you configure via file or additional env vars where to find each of these.  My earlier attempt to set `ANDROID_HOME` to the platform-tools dir didn't work and why I did a symlink.

Comment: ANDROID_HOME should point to the sdk dir, not the platforms dir in it